# Check if date range is filled in Javascript with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

I am building a scheduling application with Express. I have a calendar view that displays a monthly calendar.

Each day must be completely covered; whether shifts overlap or not, there must be at least one person on a shift at all times.

Given an array of shifts for the day that look like this

```
{
    start: [javascript Date],
    end: [javascript Date],
    name: "James Bond",
    ...
}
```

I want to conditionally add a CSS class to highlight the day if more shifts are needed to fill it.

What is the best way tell if the time between `x` and `y` is completely filled?

Comment: What's the smallest time unit? Hours/minutes/days?

Comment: and what do you mean by completely filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show what you have tried, but I will give you pseudocode for two basic approaches for this problem.

With *either* approach, make sure that you are using half-opened intervals for your shifts.  This is represented a few different ways:

```
// interval notation:
[start, end)

// algebraicly
start <= value < end

// javascript and other code
start <= value && end > value
```

### Approach #1

- Use `Date.getTime()` on each date to get a simple numeric representation of each date.
- Find a library that implements an [**Interval Tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).
- Map all your shifts onto the tree.
- Flatten/merge the tree.
- Look for gaps.

### Approach #2

- Initialize a counter `i = 0`.
- Initialize a dictionary or list of key/value pairs.
- For each shift in the list:

  - If your start date `x` is in the shift, then increment `i`.
  - See if the start time is in the dictionary.

    - If not, add it with the key being the start datetime and the value being `1`.
    - If it is already in the dictionary, increment the value.
  - See if the end time is in the dictionary.

    - If not, add it with the key being the start datetime and the value being `-1`.
    - If it is already in the dictionary, decrement the value.
- Sort the dictionary by the datetime keys.
- Walk the dictionary, starting from `x`.

  - `i` should be starting with the number of people currently working.
  - Add the value of each dictionary item to your counter `i`.
  - If `i == 0` then nobody is working.  Return false or error.
  - If you've followed the logic, then `i` should never be negative.  Error if it is.
  - Continue until your end date `y` is reached.